Divergence Theorem Under Weaker Hypothesis
The book I'm reading (about electromagnetism) seems to use a version of the divergence theorem stronger than the one I know the proof of.
I know infact that the theorem holds for a bounded open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^1$ boundary and $C^1(\bar{U})$ ($\bar{U}$ is the closure of $U$) vector fields.
The author however seems to use the theorem also for vector fields that are $C^1(U) \cap C(\bar{U})$ with bounded derivatives in $U$.
I tried to prove the theorem under these hypothesis, by considering a sequence $U_n$ of sets with $C^\infty$ boundary such that $U_n \subset \subset U_{n+1} \subset \subset U$, and such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n = U$ (I already know a proof of the existence of such a sequnce), so that I can apply gauss theorem to them.
Here I'm stuck however, since I can't prove that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\partial U_n} v \cdot dS \to \int_{\partial U} v \cdot dS 
\end{equation}
In that case the proof would be over since
\begin{equation}
\int_{\partial U_n} v \cdot dS = \int_{U_n} \nabla \cdot v \to \int_{U} \nabla \cdot v
\end{equation}
and we would have the desired equality.
How can I do that step? Is the theorem even true under such hypothesis?
Thanks in advance.

well simply having a $C^1(U)$ vector field wouldn’t even ensure that $\text{div}(v)\in L^1(U)$, so you can’t even write down the divergence integral. So, really you should assume $v\in H^1(U)\cap C(\overline{U})$. If you’re simply reading an E&M book, then they’re not always going to be precise with the regularities of the functions/domains involved, for that you’re going to have to refer to more specialized books on potential theory, or elliptic PDEs.

@peek-a-boo Yes, I'm editing the question, I'm also assuming derivatives to be bounded

Let $T_1(v)=\int_U \nabla\cdot v\, dV$ and $T_2(v)=\int_{\partial U}\gamma(v)\cdot \nu\, dS$, where $\gamma$ is the trace operator (see Evans section 5.5 Theorem 1) and $\nu$ the outward unit normal. Then, $T_1,T_2:H^1(U;\Bbb{R}^n)\to \Bbb{R}$ are both linear and continuous (continuity of $T_1$ is obvious since we’re using the $H^1$ norm, while the well-definition and continuity of $T_2$ are due to the trace theorem).
Now both $T_1$ and $T_2$ agree on the space $C^{\infty}(\overline{U};\Bbb{R}^n)$ by the usual divergence theorem; also this space is dense in $H^1(U;\Bbb{R}^n)$ because $U$ has $C^1$ boundary (see Evans section 5.3, Theorem 3). So by density, we must have $T_1=T_2$ on all of $H^1(U;\Bbb{R}^n)$.
So in short, what you really need is the trace theorem from the theory of Sobolev spaces.

I don't think I can thank you enough, you are my saviour! I will accept the answer and close the question as soon as I've read enough about Sobolev spaces to properly understand your answer, so to make shure I don't encounter further doubts. Thank you so much!
